# Make the server not send me same messages when i enter a chat room many times?

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

If I enter into a chat room, I will receive some messages.Then I sign out my account.Of course, I exit the chat room too.But I enter into the same chat room next time, I receive the same messages also.I mean, when I enter into a chat room many times, the server should not send me the same messages,the server should send me messages which I have never received.What should I do??
There is an option in ejabberd.cfg,"history_size",but it does not meet my needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Section 7.2.15 of XEP-0045](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-managehistory) specifies how you can ask to limit the amount of message history you get when entering the room.  When reentering the room, your client could note the timestamp of the last message it got, and ask to get only messages after that time:

```xml
<presence
    from='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    id='n13mt3l'
    to='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit/thirdwitch'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'>
    <history since='1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'/>
  </x>
</presence>
```

Comment: that's seems to be a good idea, but the time on client and server maybe different. Can client get the time when it last sign out from  the server? if so,the solution is very good.